# Manage the calls queue on a specific webservice

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a mobile App which communicate with the server using RESTFul WebAPI services thanks to a .NET WebApi program running on the server. The application is about adding and selling products. At each sell of a product, we make -1 on the total amount of that product in stock, in database. 
The app will be used by many users and all the users will be able to sale the same product at the same time if the product stock is sufficient. To sell a product and so take it out of the stock, I need to be sure that the product is still available. As many users will be able to sell it at the same time, I need to create a waiting queue on that webservice that will check if there are other requests waiting and processing before firing the request to avoid transactions error like the product is no more available but the sell was done before knowing it. 
Does somebody knows how to create a waiting queue on a webservice ? Is this about threading or something ?

Theoretically, what I think is the best solution is that everytime that a product is being sold, we put the request in a different thread that will be put behind another one and will be executed once the other threads will finish and the stock (in Database) of that product is available for the current sell.

But I have no idea how to do that, may someone advise or help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that web service "queue" could be done using an `AutoResetEvent`.

If you protect the critical code where your business logic checks if there's stock for some product and, if there's stock, it substracts one from the counter, any thread (request) trying to enter the whole critical code will wait until the thread that could enter that code finishes its execution and sets the reset event.

Pseudo-code:

```
// This should be declared at your class level and it should be a static field/property
AutoReset autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// Only one thread will be able to reach the code within this if statement.
// You decide if you want to provide a timeout or you want to wait forever,
// and all threads will wait until one exits the critical code protected by the event
if(autoReset.WaitOne(3000))
{
     try
     {
         // Product selling stuff
     }
     finally
     {
         autoReset.Set();
     }
}
else
{
    // Thread waited 3 seconds. Maybe you should do something in order to prevent users'
    // wait time when they want to sell something.
}
```

[Learn more about `AutoResetEvent` in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

Comment: @HubertSolecki I'm glad to hear that! I believe that your discovering about `AutoResetEvent` will open you a lot of doors to other use cases! ;)